# How to implement a script?

Tags: arcpy, implementation

I am currently having trouble implementing a script suggested for a question I previously posted [Using arcpy.da.SearchCursor to script snapping one set of points to location of another set of points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/298606/129755)
The suggested script is:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("POLYGONS", "CENTROID")
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("POINTS", "POINT_X_Y_Z_M")
# TRANSFER CENTROID XY TO POINTS TABLE
arcpy.AddJoin_management("POINTS", "POINT_ID", "POLYGONS", "PGON_ID")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("POINTS", "centres.POINT_X", "[POLYGONS.CENTROID_X]")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("POINTS", "centres.POINT_Y", "[POLYGONS.CENTROID_Y]")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("POINTS", "POLYGONS")
# AND MOVE POINTS
arcpy.CalculateField_management("POINTS", "Shape",
                                "arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!)")
```

I tried updating the "POINTS' and 'POLYGONS" to my point and polygon shape files. Unfortunately I am unsure what I'm doing wrong/missing in the implementation.

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\BuildingFootprints_XY", "CENTROID")
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\Situs", "POINT_X_Y_Z_M")
# TRANSFER CENTROID XY TO POINTS TABLE
arcpy.AddJoin_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\SITUS", "PARCEL", "P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\BuildingFootprints_XY", "PARCEL")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\Situs", "POINT_X", "[POLYGONS.CENTROID_X]")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\Situs", "POINT_Y", "[POLYGONS.CENTROID_Y]")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\Situs", "P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\BuildingFootprints_XY")
# AND MOVE POINTS
arcpy.CalculateField_management("P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\SITUS_SNAP", "Shape",
                                "arcpy.Point( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!)")
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to include a problem statement (where the error occurs, and what error is generated). In general, it is better to edit the previous question than create a new question which references a closed question.

Comment: @Vince I wouldn't suggest editing the previous question in this instance because to do so would probably invalidate one of its three existing answers. I agree with your first sentence 100%.

Comment: Add the Errors and also full script, it's tough to help without more information.

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake about path string.

Add letter `r` at the beginning of all string which include path. Like

```
r"P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\BuildingFootprints_XY"
r"P:\PolygonCentroid.gdb\Situs"
```

Or add one more backslash next to other backslahes.

```
"P:\\PolygonCentroid.gdb\\BuildingFootprints_XY"
"P:\\PolygonCentroid.gdb\\Situs"
```

Or change all `\`(backslash) into `/`(forward slash)

```
"P:/PolygonCentroid.gdb/BuildingFootprints_XY"
"P:/PolygonCentroid.gdb/Situs"
```